# Agenda issue when using CosmosDB - agenda:db_init index creation failed

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, agenda

I am using agenda v5.0.0 with MongoDB client. I can establish connectivity but looks like the issue is with creating the index which fails. Bellow is my code structure.

agenda.ts:

```
import Agenda from 'agenda',
import {MongoClient} from 'mongodb',
import {cosmosDBConfig} from '../config/cosmosDBConfig';

const encodedConnectionString = encodeURIComponent(cosmosDBConfig.connectionString);

const mongoConnectionString = `mongodb://${cosmosDBConfig.username}:${encodedConnectionString}@${cosmosDBConfig.host}:${cosmosDBConfig.port}/${cosmosDBConfig.database}?ssl=${cosmosDBConfig.ssl}`;

const mongoDb = new MongoClient(mongoConnectionString).db(cosmosDBConfig.database);

const AgendaSingleton = new Agenda({
   mongo: mongoDB,
   db: {
     address: mongoConnectionStringAgenda,
     collection: cosmosDBConfig.collection,
   }
   sort: {nextRunAt: 1},
});

export {AgendaSingleton};
```

testAgenda.ts

```
import {AgendaSingleton} from '../utils/agenda';

AgendaSingleton.define('Test Job 1', async job => {
    console.log('Test Job 1 run');
});

AgendaSingleton.every('3 minutes', 'Test Job 1');
```

When I run testAgenda file I get the following log "agenda:db_init index creation failed" and then the following error:

```
const timeout = new MongoServerSelectError(

MongoServerSelectionError: connection <monito> to [::1]:10255

)
```

Comment: are you using vCore?

Comment: Hi @Sajeetharan, Can you please expand on this? I am developing on a Macbook and using Azure Cosmos DB Emulator as a docker image.

Comment: v5.0.0 with MongoDB client , what do you mean by this?

Comment: I mean I am using MongoDB client and passing it to the agenda instance. See example above.

Comment: ya I understand, question here is Mongo 5.0 is not supported unless you are using vCore.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/vcore/introduction

Comment: Mongo is at version 4.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254853/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-marco).